# CQL - How to set Neo4j node property using a dynamic key in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I'm trying to fix up incorrect data in my Neo4j database, and I'd like to have just a cypher to do the updating rather than transferring millions of rows to a custom application and back.

I've created a Read query that's using dynamic keys to search through every property on all nodes of a labels I specify for various types of issues - in this case, an incorrectly serialized string. The issue I'm running into is that while the Read query using dynamic keys works great:

```
MATCH (n:xLabelNamex) 
WITH 
    n, 
    [x IN keys(n) 
        WHERE n[x] STARTS WITH "\"" 
        AND n[x] ENDS WITH "\""
    ] AS doesMatch 
WHERE size(doesMatch) > 0 
UNWIND doesMatch AS label 
    MATCH (m:xLabelNamex) 
    WHERE id(n)=id(m)
    RETURN SUBSTRING(m[label], 1, SIZE(m[label]) - 2)
```

But if I leave everything the same, and change the last line from

```
RETURN SUBSTRING(m[label], 1, SIZE(m[label]) - 2)
```

to:

```
SET m[label] = SUBSTRING(m[label], 1, length(m[label]) - 2)
```

Results in the error:

```
Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, whitespace, a relationship pattern, '(', '.', '=' or "+=" (line 12, column 10 (offset: 255))
"    SET m[label] = SUBSTRING(m[label], 1, SIZE(m[label]) - 2)"
          ^
```

Is there a way to do this, or am I going down the wrong road here?

*Looking at the discussions on Github, I see that the addition of the reading of nodes using dynamic keys was added a little over a year ago, but it looks like they made it specifically targeted towards Read only. I started digging through Neo's source, but it's a behemoth. Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: AFAIK, you are correct, writing to dynamically-keyed properties is not supported natively in Cypher. However, there are many options in `apoc` to do so.

Comment: Apoc looks amazing, thank you! There's a ton of functions here, any pointers on where you think I should start looking in the documentation for what I want to do?

Comment: I haven't worked with it in a while, but I believe you can create a Map with `apoc.map.fromPairs()`, pass in the dynamically generated key, value pair, then `SET m += result` where result is whatever you call the procedure result. If your project doesn't prevent you from using betas, I would suggest switching to 3.1 and get the newest APOC, it allows you to call `apoc.map` as a function instead of a procedure.

Comment: This project requires cutting edge technology in many areas, so betas and the like are pretty much a given - I'll be looking into 3.1. Thank you for your help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming in after this, the library Tore suggested - APOC - just released version 3.0.4.2 which introduced "apoc.create.setProperty", and does exactly what I need. Additionally, I found that regexes are MUCH faster in Neo4j than straight text searches (one order of magnitude faster), so I went with that as well.

My final cypher came out to be:

```
MATCH (n:xLabelNamex) 
WITH 
    n, 
    [x IN keys(n) 
        WHERE n[x] =~ '".*"'
    ] AS doesMatch 
WHERE size(doesMatch) > 0 
UNWIND doesMatch AS label 
    MATCH (m:xLabelNamex) 
    WHERE id(n)=id(m)
    CALL apoc.create.setProperty(m, label, SUBSTRING(m[label], 1, SIZE(m[label]) - 2))
    YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Works like a charm.

Props to Tore, thank you again!